# mkdirections request- set soucre from tableview cell label array

Tags: mkmapview, directions, driving-directions

I have a tableview populated with an array of business name labels and address labels and a detail view controller with a map view and a text field to show the turn by turn directions. I want to use the business address label text as the destination for a MKDirections request when the user selects a tableview cell and show directions in the detail view controller. How do I pass the label text to the directions request when a cell is selected. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question is too broad and it's not clear where you're stuck.  Respond to the cell selection using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method.  In there, retrieve the business name from the data source.  Then push/present/segue to your detail view controller, etc...  You'll need to narrow the question down and ask a separate question for each step.  Before asking, also search on SO.  You will find many examples of each step involved in what you want to do.  Include the code you attempted in your questions.